# In Eclipse, is there a generic Provider for all kinds of content?

Tags: eclipse-juno

In Eclipse, I would like to enumerate all the content from every registered Provider. Is there such an interface?

Answer (score 1):

At least in my installation that does not search files at all. That is instead the same old ["Ctrl-3" quick access](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.3-200706251500/whatsnew/eclipse-news-part1.html) which allows you to access UI elements by typing their name. Try "pack" to see it listing the package explorer and similar things.

For quickly locating files you should use Ctrl-R (Open Resource) instead or use the normal File Search.